# custom model binder with complex type MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have the following ViewModel and i would like to create a custom binder to bind subclasses (LogOnModel, ChangePasswordModel).

```
public class LogOnViewModel
{
    public string NextStep { get; set; }
    public string PreviousStep { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    public bool MustChangePassword { get; set; }
    public bool MustAgreeNewPrivacyStatement { get; set; }
    public LogOnModel logOnModel { get; set; }
    public ChangePasswordModel changePasswordModel { get; set; }
}
```

I was able to create my custom binder (inherit from DefaultModelBinder) but never was able to get a full VALIDATED model (ModelState populated) back into my controller. It's working fine for simple type (string, bool, ....) but a bit more complicated with complex type (subclass).

Is MVC 3 Futures the answer to my question or someone was able to override DefaultModelbinder to bind subclasses?

Thanks,
Michel

Comment: Michel, I don't really understand what you're asking. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I want to create a custom binder to bind my LogOnViewModel (with subclasses). I can't get the subclasses to be bind.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create custom model binders for `LogOnModel` and `ChangePasswordModel` as well; your custom model binder doesn't know automatically how to bind your complex types.